# Use wildcard search in file path c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, wildcard

I am trying to use a wildcard search that searches my desktop for anything that ends with the word `test`.

I have this (ExcelToDataTable) takes in a `string` as the parameter:

```
ExcelToDataTable(@"C:\Users\name\Desktop\*test.xls");
```

Then I have my method that does some things with the data I am trying to pull in from the sheet named with test:

```
public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string filePath)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {

     }
 }
```

So my question is, with my provided example, is there a way to use a wildcard and feed that into my `ExcelToDataTable` method? I am wanting to find every .xls file on my desktop that has the word `test` at the end...

Thanks

Comment: also there are extension methods using linq to search for files using the key word `.EndWith()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a new method, "one level up" that accepts a directory path, finds all the xls files in it, and passes them to your method in a list.

```
 public static List<DataTable> ProcessDataTables(string dirPath)
    {
               xlsFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*test.xls")
               var results = new List<DataTable>
               foreach(var file in xlsFiles) 
                     results.Append(ExcelToDataTable(file))
               return results
    }
```

You should consider some sanity-checking in there (like checking that `dirPath` is actually a path to a directory that exists, anything that calls this is OK with an empty list as a return value in case no xls files exist, etc.. )

In general,  it's also best practice to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` instead of hard-coding "your" desktop.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following for example lets say I want to find files that end with `.jpg and .txt` I could do the following

```
var fi = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles().
     Where(f => !(f.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg") || f.Name.EndsWith(".txt"))).ToArray();
```

in your case if you are looking for a file that ends with a `.text` ext then do the following

```
var fi = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles().
    Where(f => !(f.FullName.EndsWith(".text") || f.Name.EndsWith(".Text"))).ToArray();
```

you could also do a Google search on the following, `C# Linq Directory.EnumerateFiles()` Method